# Show exact number of matches even for large (>99) numbers

Tags: neovim, search

When I search for something `/search-term` and it shows up more than 100 times in my file, vim shows me that I'm on match `x/>99` instead of `x/121` etc.

For smaller numbers it shows me the exact number of total matches: `10/23`, but with more than 99 total matches it doesn't show the exact number of matches anymore.

How do I make it show me the total exact number of matches anyway?

Comment: not possible, this limit is hard coded for performance reasons.

Answer (score 10):

If your Vim binary includes the patch [8.2.0877](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.2.0877), you can get the search statistics via the `searchcount()` function.  And the latter is not limited to 99 matches.

You can invoke it right after a `/` search with a `CmdlineLeave` autocmd, and right after a `n` motion by installing a wrapper mapping around the latter.

[Example](https://github.com/lacygoill/vim-search/blob/6bd25440074834cfa4030d7bd924859cbe72eeca/autoload/search.vim#L88-L137):

```
const s:MAXCOUNT = 1000
const s:TIMEOUT = 500

augroup index_after_slash | au!
    au CmdlineLeave /,\? call s:index_after_slash()
augroup END

fu s:index_after_slash() abort
    if getcmdline() is# '' || state() =~# 'm'
        return
    endif
    call timer_start(0, {-> mode() =~# '[nv]' ? s:search_index() : 0})
endfu

fu s:search_index() abort
    try
        let result = searchcount(#{maxcount: s:MAXCOUNT, timeout: s:TIMEOUT})
        let [current, total, incomplete] = [result.current, result.total, result.incomplete]
    catch
        echohl ErrorMsg | echom v:exception | echohl NONE
        return ''
    endtry
    let msg = ''
    let pat = substitute(@/, '\%x00', '^@', 'g')
    if incomplete == 0
        let msg = printf('[%*d/%d] %s', len(total), current, total, pat)
    elseif incomplete == 1 " recomputing took too much time
        let msg = printf('[?/??] '..%s', pat)
    elseif incomplete == 2 " too many matches
        if result.total == (result.maxcount+1) && result.current <= result.maxcount
            let msg = printf('[%*d/>%d] %s', len(total-1), current, total-1, pat)
        else
            let msg = printf('[>%*d/>%d] %s', len(total-1), current-1, total-1, pat)
        endif
    endif
    if strchars(msg, 1) > (v:echospace + (&cmdheight-1)*&columns)
        let n = v:echospace - 3
        let [n1, n2] = n%2 ? [n/2, n/2] : [n/2-1, n/2]
        let msg = matchlist(msg, '\(.\{' .. n1 .. '}\).*\(.\{' .. n2 .. '}\)')[1:2]->join('...')
    endif
    echo msg
    return ''
endfu

nmap n <plug>(n)<plug>(search_index)
nmap N <plug>(N)<plug>(search_index)
nno <plug>(n) n
nno <plug>(N) N
nno <expr> <plug>(search_index) <sid>search_index()
```

`searchcount()` won't show a total amount of matches greater than 1000.  If that's not enough, increase `s:MAXCOUNT`.
And it will stop trying to compute the number of matches after half-a-second.  If that's too long, decrease `s:TIMEOUT`.

Note that increasing `s:MAXCOUNT` and `s:TIMEOUT` may have a negative impact on Vim's performance.  The values used in the previous snippet work for me; they may or may not work for you.  I guess it depends on the machine you're using and/or on the patterns you're usually looking for.  Take that into consideration before setting these parameters.

You can improve the performance by rewriting the code in Vim9 script:

```
vim9script

const MAXCOUNT: number = 1'000
const TIMEOUT: number = 500

augroup index_after_slash | au!
    au CmdlineLeave /,\? IndexAfterSlash()
augroup END

def IndexAfterSlash()
    if getcmdline() == '' || state() =~ 'm'
        return
    endif
    timer_start(0, () => mode() =~ '[nv]' ? SearchIndex() : 0)
enddef

def SearchIndex(): string
    var incomplete: number
    var total: number
    var current: number
    var result: dict<any>
    try
        result = searchcount({maxcount: MAXCOUNT, timeout: TIMEOUT})
        current = result.current
        total = result.total
        incomplete = result.incomplete
    catch
        echohl ErrorMsg | echom v:exception | echohl NONE
        return ''
    endtry
    var msg: string = ''
    var pat: string = getreg('/')->substitute('\%x00', '^@', 'g')
    if incomplete == 0
        msg = printf('[%*d/%d] %s', len(total), current, total, pat)
    elseif incomplete == 1 # recomputing took too much time
        msg = printf('[?/??] %s', pat)
    elseif incomplete == 2 # too many matches
        if result.total == (result.maxcount + 1) && result.current <= result.maxcount
            msg = printf('[%*d/>%d] %s', len(total - 1), current, total - 1, pat)
        else
            msg = printf('[>%*d/>%d] %s', len(total - 1), current - 1, total - 1, pat)
        endif
    endif
    if strchars(msg, 1) > (v:echospace + (&cmdheight - 1) * &columns)
        var n: number = v:echospace - 3
        var n1: number = n % 2 ? n / 2 : n / 2 - 1
        var n2: number = n / 2
        var matchlist: list<string> = matchlist(msg, '\(.\{' .. n1 .. '}\).*\(.\{' .. n2 .. '}\)')
        msg = matchlist[1] .. '...' .. matchlist[2]
    endif
    echo msg
    return ''
enddef

nmap n <plug>(n)<plug>(search_index)
nmap N <plug>(N)<plug>(search_index)
nno <plug>(n) n
nno <plug>(N) N
nno <expr> <plug>(search_index) <sid>SearchIndex()
```

This requires a recent Vim version. It works on 8.2.2332.

---

For more info, see:

- [`:h searchcount()`](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#searchcount())
- [`:h vim9`](https://vimhelp.org/vim9.txt.html)
- [`:h :def`](https://vimhelp.org/vim9.txt.html#:def)

Comment: Really cool answer! Maybe it would be worth adding a warning about the potential performances issues when you increase `s:MAXCOUNT` and `s:TIMEOUT` because originally that's why vim has the limits I mention in my answer. But anyway I didn't know this function so that a very interesting answer.

Answer (score 7):

I assume you are talking of the built-in search counter here
[image]

First for users who don't know, this search counter is controlled by the `S` flag in `shortmess` [`:h 'shortmess'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27shortmess%27)

```
  S     do not show search count message when searching, e.g.
        "[1/5]"
```

but the doc doesn't mention how to change the limit, so let's have a look at vim source code:

[here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/be7a50c22f63478a6e64fe6b932a847830191b95/src/search.c#L40) we have the define `#define SEARCH_STAT_DEF_MAX_COUNT 99`.

This value is passed to `cmdline_search_stat` [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/be7a50c22f63478a6e64fe6b932a847830191b95/src/search.c#L1611-L1622).

And [here](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/be7a50c22f63478a6e64fe6b932a847830191b95/src/search.c#L3130-L3132) in `cmdline_search_stat` you can see how this value is used. When there is more than 99 matches the source code will use this limit:

```
if (stat.incomplete == 1)
    vim_snprintf(t, SEARCH_STAT_BUF_LEN, "[?/??]");
else if (stat.cnt > maxcount && stat.cur > maxcount)
    vim_snprintf(t, SEARCH_STAT_BUF_LEN, "[>%d/>%d]", maxcount, maxcount);
else if (stat.cnt > maxcount)
    vim_snprintf(t, SEARCH_STAT_BUF_LEN, "[%d/>%d]", stat.cur, maxcount);
else
    vim_snprintf(t, SEARCH_STAT_BUF_LEN, "[%d/%d]", stat.cur, stat.cnt);
```

So you can't change that without changing Vim's sources.

And for neovim the answer is the same because the code [is pretty similar](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/267bc57d21fd7cc995ea91028de912d92d5fd662/src/nvim/search.c#L4325-L4333) it just doesn't use a constant to hold the `99` limit.

Comment: Is it possible in neovim?

Comment: Probably not but I'll let you check the docs and the code by yourself :)

Comment: I don't think so, since this feature comes from a vim patch and was later merged into neovim.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Indeed the code is [pretty similar](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/267bc57d21fd7cc995ea91028de912d92d5fd662/src/nvim/search.c#L4325-L4333)

Answer (score 3):

There are several plugins that support showing the number of matchings, for example, [vim-indexed-search](https://github.com/henrik/vim-indexed-search). In the alternatives section, you can also find several similar plugins.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Anzu](https://github.com/osyo-manga/vim-anzu) which counts up to 1000 results by default.

You can change this limit:

```
let g:anzu_search_limit = 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out both vim/neovim have this limit hardcoded, presumably for performance reasons. It seems very conservative in these days.

For a non-built in solution i find FZF's `:BLines` the quickest and best solution.

Answer (score 0):

For a quick check, try:

```lua
:lua print(vim.inspect(vim.fn.searchcount { maxcount = 0 }))
```

Example output:

```lua
{
  current = 314,
  exact_match = 1,
  incomplete = 0,
  maxcount = 0,
  total = 21782
}
```

---

#### Replacing the statusline

/u/Adk9p provides [the following](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/wrj7eu/help_show_the_full_number_of_search_occurrences/ikswlfo/) lua-based method:

> You can't change the max value that is shown in the msgbuf without
> recompiling. The 99 value comes from a macro in the code ([the
> macro](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/700a6fb9d4689ebfeea1139370351eafef74f302/src/nvim/search.h#L54),
> [where it's
> used](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/700a6fb9d4689ebfeea1139370351eafef74f302/src/nvim/search.c#L1404-L1411)).
>
> What you can do instead is hide it with `set shortmess +=S` (`:h shortmess`) and then create your own display in your statusline/winbar
> using `:h searchcount()`
>
> ```lua
> if vim.v.hlsearch == 1 then
>   local sinfo = vim.fn.searchcount { maxcount = 0 }
>   local search_stat = sinfo.incomplete > 0 and '[?/?]'
>     or sinfo.total > 0 and ('[%s/%s]'):format(sinfo.current, sinfo.total)
>     or nil
>
>   if search_stat ~= nil then
>     -- add search_stat to statusline/winbar
>   end
> end
> ```

...Now, just return `search_stat` and call the function from your statusline appropriately. (Or simpler and less likely to hurt performance: just map it to a keybinding.)

A few useful performance tweaks for this would be to cache calculations until a new search is performed or the cursor moves to the next position. I'm not sure if neovim already does some of this internally. Also, limit the file size (e.g. `10MB`), and limit `maxcount = 100000`.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble To help [heat up](https://xkcd.com/1172/) a cold room, of course. :)