# Can you get a count on a search where the count is > 1000 matches?

Tags: counting, pattern

I have a file listing all the books I have read since 2013. I told someone I read x books a week and they didn't believe me so I started doing it :)

The data looks like this. The last column is the count of books read. I have a function that renumbers the entries as they may be read years apart.

```
Start: 1 Aug 2013

%Daniel Silva   Spy  Isralie%
!Gabriel Allon Series!
    The Rembrandt Affair    Year 2013   1
    The Secret Servant  Year 2013   2
    Moscow Rules    Year 2013   3
    The Defector    Year 2013   4
    The Messenger   Year 2013   5
    Prince of Fire  Year 2013   6
    Portrait of a Spy   Year 2013   7
    The Fallen Angel    Year 2013   8
    The English Girl    Feb 2019    9
```

Being clumsy fingered I miss the `tab` between the year and the count sometimes so I have this search `\v^\s+\S` to check that the count from the search matches the last count at the document end. That worked until I hit > 1000 books this year. Can I get a count of pattern matches where the count is > 1000 some other way?

[image: Result of pattern match]

Comment: Yes, this is possible using the `searchcount()` function, see e.g. this example here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26304/71

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `:s[ubstitute]` command's [`n` flag](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%3As_n). As described under [`:h count-items`](https://vimhelp.org/tips.txt.html#count-items):

> To count how often any pattern occurs in the current buffer use the substitute command and add the 'n' flag to avoid the substitution.

So...

```
:%s/\v^\s+\S//n
```

Or if you've already searched for the pattern you could, of course, just do...

```
:%s///n
```

Either way, this handles counts higher than 1000.

Comment: @b layer Thanks. I should have remembered that