# How can I get the number of matches of pattern without altering the search buffer nor moving the cursor?

Tags: vimscript, search, autocmd, cursor-movement, counting

My end goal is to be able to highlight all the matches of the word being typed and echo  their number, but this question is about one specific aspect of this, which I've been having trouble with, which is getting the number of those matches without altering the `/` buffer nor moving the curosor.

From the name, [`searchcount`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#searchcount%28%29) seemed promising, but in reality it isn't (if I understood correctly), because it has to do with the actual "last search", i.e. what you do with `/` or `:s`, whereas I'm actually using [`matchadd`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#matchadd%28%29) to highlight the matches of a given text, and I want the count of *those* matches.

So I thought that I could give `execute('%s/the-text//gn')` a try, but apparently it's not the right tool: the following toy example shows `echo`s the number of characters being written, but writing `ciao` in a file results in `oaic`, just like `echo execute('%s/.//gn')->split('\n')[0]`¹ is causing the cursor to go back to the beginning of the line upon each keystroke.

```
augroup Foo
  autocmd!
  autocmd TextChangedI,TextChangedP * call <SID>foo()
  fun s:foo()
    echo execute('%s/.//gn')->split('\n')[0]
  endf
augroup END
```

Note that changing `echo execute('%s/.//gn')->split('\n')[0]` to `echo "bla"` or even `echo execute('echo "ciao"')->split('\n')[0]` doesn't cause the same issue, so `echo` and `execute` seem both innocent, whereas `:s` seems to be causing the issue.

---

(¹) The `->split('\n')[0]` is to avoid the `Press ENTER or type command to continue` prompt.

Comment: `:help getmatches()` is mentioned at the bottom of `:help matchadd()`.

Comment: the [searchcount()](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#searchcount%28%29) function accepts a `pattern` argument! See also [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26304/71) which shows a complete example for the searchcount() function. You just need to provide a pattern to it

Comment: Does [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23650554/10538725) help? Restoring the cursor position from backtick register works for me; simply put `let a = getpos("'\`") | call cursor(a[1], a[2])` after the `execute` line.

Comment: @Hoblovski, it seems to work, thanks!

Comment: I've also asked a follow up question [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42534/popup-to-show-number-of-matches-of-a-given-string-while-in-insert-mode-and-whil).

Comment: @romainl, `getmatches` returns a list of `{'group': ?, 'pattern': ?, 'priority': ?, 'id': ?}`, so it's not about the list of matches relative to one `matchadd` command.