# Popup to show number of matches of a given string while in insert mode, and while completion popup is being shown

Tags: autocmd, autocompletion, cursor-movement, popup-menu, popup

This is a follow up to a [previous question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42519/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-matches-of-pattern-without-altering-the-search-buffe?noredirect=1#comment76137_42519).

Thanks to that, I could come up with this `augroup`:

```
augroup Foo
  autocmd!
  autocmd TextChangedI,TextChangedP * call <SID>foo()
  fun s:foo()
    let msg = execute('%s/.//gn')->split('\n')[0]
    echo msg
    let a = getpos("'`")
    call cursor(a[1], a[2])
    call popup_atcursor(msg->split('\n')[0], #{})
  endf
augroup END
```

which makes the current number of characters in the file to be shown both in the command line, via `:echo`, and in a popup, via `popup_atcursor`.

The weird thing about the latter is that it doesn't get updated if another popup, for me the one shown by YCM, is showing. Here's a live demo:

[image: asciicast]

You can see that

- when I enter insert mode and write the first character, "my" popup is shown, with a given number
- upon entering the second character, the number in my popup is updated **and** YCM's popup pops up (because I have `let g:ycm_min_num_of_chars_for_completion = 2` in my vimrc),
- upon entering further characters such that the YCM popup is not dismissed, my popup doesn't update anymore (whereas the text `echo`d in the command line does),
- as soon as I type one character that causes YCM's popup to be dismissed, then my popup is updated.

The fact that `echo` is indeed printing text even while YCM's popup is up is a proof that the `s:foo` function is indeed running for every single character I type.

However, it looks like the call to `call popup_atcursor(msg->split('\n')[0], #{})` is not updating the popup.

Why is this the case?

---

Adding `call popup_clear()` right before `call popup_atcursor(msg->split('\n')[0], #{})` seems to do the trick, but I suspect it's not really the right thing to do?

Comment: popup_atcursor creates a new popup each time, it doesn’t update an existing one (IIRC). You need to handle that yourself.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, what I observe seem to prove that successive calls to `popup_atcursor` while the other popup is shown are ineffective, though.

Comment: Why are you not using the `searchcount()` function?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, because I'm not using `/` but setting up matches via `matchadd` (see the question I linked at the top).

Comment: Yes, that has nothing to do with it!. `searchcount()` can be used with a separate pattern as I have mentioned [before](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/42519/how-can-i-get-the-number-of-matches-of-pattern-without-altering-the-search-buffe?noredirect=1#comment76126_42519). That's exactly the purpose for the `searchcount()` function